# Unwanted rotation of images

Tags: graphics, rotating, subcaption

I have three images included with `\subcaptionbox` in a figure, but the problem is that I get one of the images, which is vertical, rotated 90° automatically and I don't want it. Is there any way I could avoid this rotation? I don't want to change each image that is rotated. In the code it is rotated so it can be vertical.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{framed}
            \centering
            \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:labprob}}{%
                \includegraphics[width=.345\textwidth,angle=-90]{2probetas.jpg}%
            }\hspace{0.2cm}
            \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:labpump}}{%
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=4.5cm]{labpump.jpg}%
            }\hspace{0.2cm}
            \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:labbuch}}{%
                \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{2Buchner.jpg}%
            }
            \end{framed}
            \caption{Equipment and steps for the suspensibility test. (a) Graduated cylinders (b) Peristaltic pump (c) Vacuum and Büchner funnel}
            \label{fig:suspensibilityequip}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `angle=-90` option from the first `\includegraphics` command. Apart from that, you might want to keep in mind that images will be distorted if you add both  `width` and `height`.

Comment: Adding to what @leandriis says: You can also include the `keepaspectratio` option. This way a graphic will be as big as possible with the restraints that it is not higher than your `height` and not wider than your `width` without distortion.

Comment: @leandriis the problem is that if I remove the angle=-90 the original image which is vertical, gets horizontal and that is what I am trying to fix

Comment: @Cecilia: Could you please add a screenshot of the output? If I use an example image in portrait orientation such as `example-image-golden-upright` and remove the `angle=90` option, [the image is inserted in portrait orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb7S2.png).  Apart from that: How did you determine the orientation of the original image? Some image viewers seem to autorotate images when viewing while the original file keeps its orientation.

Comment: Depending on source, image format and metadata (e.g exif tag) the image can hold its own idea about which way up it was taken/built and viewed. If that is the case it may be easier to process a large batch of images with an exif program 1st, for a [rant see](http://keyj.emphy.de/exif-orientation-rant/)  some editors may not use the meta tags correctly. It WAS mainly JPeG and TIfF but newer PNGs can have similar issues and that can translate over via PDF. Apparently there are 8 different orientations possible (I thought it was 4) see https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

Comment: Ok just leaving a comment here for others stumbling by that may want to test EXIF handling during import. Here are samples of all 16 ! ways a JPG image can be orientated !! https://github.com/chrdavis/JPEGAutoRotator/tree/master/EXIF%20Test%20Files I cant yet find examples for PNG as its chunk tags are fairly new (2017) but time will tell.