# Image crosswise in CV

Tags: lyx, moderncv, cv

I'm using LaTeX/LyX for some while now and also to create my CV. So far, no problem. Recently, I made some new photos and I noticed that when I insert them in the CV template, that the image will get turned by 90°. No matter which size I choose. Do I use the former image, then it's no problem. I tried to turn the image by 90° on its own but no change.
Anybody an idea?

edit: My preamble:

```
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
% possible themes are "classic" and "casual"
% optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)

% required
\firstname{Name}
% required
\familyname{Surname}

% optional, remove the line if not wanted
\title{Curriculum Vitae}

% optional
% \address{street and number}{postcode city}
% '\\' adds a line break
\address{Street}{Zip Code City\protect\\[0.1em] Country\protect\\[0.2em]}

% optional
\mobile{+number}

% optional
\email{person@provider}

% optional
% \photo[height]{name}
% 'height' is the height the picture is resized to
% 'name' is the name of the picture file
\photo[90pt]{image}

% optional
\quote{}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.6cm}
```

The LyX Version is 2.1.4, 24. July 2015
Tried *.jpg and *.png. With the former image it worked even without the specific file type.

part of the log file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2018.10.13)  29 JAN 2019 20:50
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**file-name.tex
(./file-name.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter do
cument class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count79
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
```

Comment: Thank you, in which way shall I complete the code snippet? This is the entire preamble. Don't know where I see the moderncv version, so I added the lyx version. The image is me... :)

Comment: Okay, you are using `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`. That is a little bit outdated, current version is TeX Live 2018. You are using the current version of `moderncv`: `Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0`. So I guess your image itself is the problem ...

Comment: 16 ways to define a rotated image makes for a nightmare see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472077/unwanted-rotation-of-images#comment1190122_472077 It may be easiest to use a graphics package that strips out any erroneous source exif definition since png generated by newer software may be doing the same with chunks

Comment: @KJO Yes, the rotation command solved it. Thank you!